# delay image load with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four divs I would like to load one after each other,

div1 load in 1 second

div2 load in 3 seconds

div3 load in 5 seconds

div4 load in 7 seconds

the code I have is

```
function runAnimation() {

    $('#main-div').fadeIn(1500, function(){
        $('#first-div').fadeIn(1500, function () {
            $('#second-div').fadeIn(3000, function(){
                $('#third-div').fadeIn(6000, function () {

                });
                $('#fourth-div').fadeIn(12000, function () {

                });
            )};
        });
    };
```

I'm not sure I have done this right, can someone explain why this would not work and provide an example?

Comment: there are a lot of reasons why this might not work. Nothing obvious with what you've posted. Just a guess, maybe it's timing? Make sure you're calling `runAnimation()` in document ready

Comment: Your description of what you want does not match your code, and is not clear. Do you want "div2" to load 3 seconds after "div1" completed loading, or 3 seconds after `runAnimation()` was called? "1500" is 1.5 seconds. "12000" is 12 seconds...

Comment: you have typos in your code, i posted a working one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

        runAnimation();
    });

    function runAnimation() {
        $('#main-div').fadeIn(1500, function () {
            $('#first-div').fadeIn(1500, function () {

                $('#second-div').fadeIn(3000, function () {
                    $('#third-div').fadeIn(6000, function () {

                    });
                    $('#fourth-div').fadeIn(12000, function () {

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

```css
  .box {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="main-div" class="box"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3920/14837486544_59d308d3ef_m.jpg" width="100"></div>
<div id="first-div" class="box">
    <p>Text inside div</p>
</div>
<div id="second-div" class="box">
    <p>Text inside div</p>
</div>
<div id="third-div" class="box">
    <p>Text inside div</p>
</div>
<div id="fourth-div" class="box">
    <p>Text inside div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: looks perfect, ill accept answer when i get this working, thanks

Comment: not sure this works with a div with text and image in

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using css

add each div with different delays

```
animation-name: fadeinLoad; 
animation-duration: 1s; 
animation-delay: 5s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinLoad {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeinLoad {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Working example

https://jsfiddle.net/dolphine/8xx1v8q3/

Comment: I like this, but how would i do it for each image ?

Answer (score -1):

or with `plain javascript`

```
setTimeout(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
         //whatever you need to do
      }, 1500);
    }, 3000);
  }, 6000);
}, 12000);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (how to fade in divs in order).

Comment: Well @MikeMcCaughan, if you re-read the question even now with the edit you made, there is not any single word as the main purpose is to `fade in` but rather to **load divs one after each other**. So if it is the condition, yes your answer is correct hence, I wrote another way to reproduce loading interval via timeout.